# How do I use variables to assign constant arguments in Python?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I'm creating an application in Python using Tkinter where there will be a grid of buttons, and I'm creating the buttons using nested for loops. When clicked, each button has a callback function which also passes two arguments containing the coordinates of itself. I tried to set this up by assigning each button with its own callback lambda like so:

```
self.board[row][col].config(command=lambda: switch(row, col))
```

However this doesn't work because rather than the callback for each function contaning its coordinates, e.g.

```
command=lambda: switch(2, 4)
```

it just contains the variables row and col, which means the values end up being 4 for every button since the loops end at 4.

So to summarise, I'm looking for a way to hard-code arguments into a function call. Obviously I can solve this by not using loops and just defining every single button explicitly, but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?  Maybe show your loop and your later call?

Comment: I think I sussed it out.  Why don't you store the `row` and `col` within whatever the object is at `board[row][col]` and then have the `command` use that object's members?

Comment: That did the trick, many thanks! This had me stumped for a good couple of hours.